# How to convert a Scala Iterable into Java util.List?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, collections

I have a written a method in Scala that is using a method written in Java -  `processSale()` method takes `util.List<Sale>` as a parameter.

But after `groupByKey()` I'm getting an `RDD[(String, Iterable[Sale])]`. I've tried to import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` and do `SaleParser.processSale(a.asJava)`.

However it gives me an `Iterable[Sale]`. How is it possible to convert it into a Java `util.List`?

```
val parseSales: RDD[(String, Sale)] = rawSales
      .map(sale => sale.Id -> sale)
      .groupByKey()
      .mapValues(a => SaleParser.processSale(???))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a.toSeq.asJava
```

Note that if this `Iterable` is actually a `Seq`, `toSeq` just returns the same object.

See [API doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) for the complete list of conversions.